# Can't get div content using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I was trying to generate PDF from HTML using jsPDF and html2canvas. It worked with full page, but not specific div using `getElementById()`. The console says

```
IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount html2canvas.js:2859
```

Here's my script

```
 <script>
        let doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.addHTML(document.getElementById('content'), function() {
            doc.save('html.pdf');
        });
    </script>
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: presume document.getElementById('content') returns something, might be best to start there

Comment: It returns [object HTMLDivElement] , i assume this should be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.addHTML()` is actually [deprecated](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML) now. The new vector-supporting API, `doc.html()`, works much better. See their [sample](https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/html2pdf/showcase_supported_html.html) for yourself. Here is the working code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" 
        integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<!-- html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.11 or higher version is needed -->

<script>
    function download() {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a3');
        pdf.html(document.getElementById('content'), {
            callback: function (pdf) {
                pdf.save('test.pdf');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

> Update: if you got a blank page, [try different versions of `html2canvas`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481588/4271117)